# intptr_t and size_t on 32/64 bit platform

Tags: c

When should you use `intptr_t` and `size_t` data types?

On a 32 bit platform, both `intptr_t` and `size_t` are set to 32 bits. On a 64 bit platform, they are set to 64 bits. Are there any usage guidelines?

When we use it along with `printf`, POSIX says use `%z` for `size_t` and says `PRIdPTR` for `intptr_t`. Can we use `%z` instead of `PRIdPTR` when trying to print an `intptr_t`?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `intptr_t` if you want to store a pointer in an integral type. Historically people often used `int` for this, but this isn’t good practice because often a pointer is larger than an `int` so you lose information; an `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer. You should use a `size_t` if you want the size or number of elements of some type; this is the result of `sizeof`, and is usually what you use to index sequential container types like arrays or `std::vector`s. Usually, they will be the same type under the hood (except for signedness), but this is not guaranteed on platforms with, e.g., [segmented memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation), where a type can only take up a fraction of the available memory.

You rarely actually want to store a pointer in an integral type; you are usually much better off leaving it as a pointer, so you probably don’t want to use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` very much. However, you often want to know the size of things, or index arrays or standard containers, so you should use `size_t` relatively often.

Answer (score 3):

> When to use `intptr_t`, `size_t` data type?

`size_t` is always available - it is part of the C language.  It is some *unsigned* type useful for indexing arrays and performing size  calculations.  It is the best width integer for indexing as it is never too narrow nor excessively wide.

Code can use `printf("%zu\n", some_size_t);` to print.

`(u)intptr_t` are optionally yet commonly implemented.  They are part of the C standard library.  They are integer types capable of round-tripping object pointers  `object *` --> `void *`  --> `intptr_t`  --> `void *` --> `object *` with a resultant pointer that equates to the original.

Code can use `printf( "%" PRIdPTR "\n", some_intptr_t);` to print.

---

> Can we use %z instead of PRIdPTR when trying to print intptr_t?

This does not make for portable code.  Aside from the difference in sign-ness, it is reasonable to encounter implementations that differ in integer width, with `intptr_t` likely be wider or as wide as `size_t`.

Comment: Commenting on an earlier version: C99 7.8:6 says “For each type that the implementation provides in <stdint.h>, the corresponding fprintf macros shall be defined …” so if a compilation platform provides `intptr_t`, it should provide `PRIdPTR` to print it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq True.  Presence of those macros could be used to steer code.

Answer (score 3):

First, you *shouldn't care* how many bits a type has (at least, in general). Use the types for their *intended purpose* and your code will be fine and portable.

Use `size_t` for anything related to the size of an object. This includes e.g. indexing of an array.

Usages for `intptr_t` are very rare, but use them whenever you need to store the value of a pointer in a *signed integer*. Often, an *unsigned integer* is a better choice, then you can use `uintptr_t`. Most of the time, you don't need to store pointers in integers and can just use ..... a pointer type.

For printing, `%z` is not a conversion specifier. `z` is a length modifier suitable for the size of a `size_t`. As `size_t` is unsigned, you need `%zu`. Also note that the `PRIdPTR` macro expands to something you should concatenate with `%` to make it a complete conversion specifier. It only contains the type specifier and necessary length modifier.

Of course, if you **know** that `uintptr_t` is the same type as `size_t`, printing it with `%zu` will succeed. But it's still wrong, there is no guarantee these types will be the same on all platforms.

Comment: `size_t` will _never_ be the same type as `intptr_t`. Did you mean `uintptr_t`?

Comment: @IanAbbott well, I meant the same *size*, but thinking about it, I'd have to explain some UB. I opt for `uintptr_t` now, thanks :)

Comment: Nice answer! It should be noted that (and perhaps this explains the rarity) `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are *optional* types. When they do exist, `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, which *are* guaranteed to exist are guaranteed to be able to represent them... and you can print those two types with `%jd` and `%ju` respectively. Additionally, it is handy to know that `size_t` is required to have a maximum value of *at least* 65535 (i.e. it is *at least* 16 bits in width, not that an increase in size has any impact on range, as we've all seen *padding bits*, which might be another noteworthy mention).

Comment: Finally, some compilers have configurations which will print a warning if you try to use the wrong format specifier/type of argument combination... and that's even when they have the same representation and alignment requirements! I'm not sure how compliant that is; I haven't really cared to research it.